# What is the meaning of the phrase "throw everything at"?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of the phrase "throw everything at"?

> 55' Newcastle begin to **throw everything at** West Ham once more as they look to take the lead for a third time!

Comment: Make maximum effort

Comment: Use _all_ their resources of strength and skill.